# javascript inject a html between

Tags: javascript

I have to insert a html line using javascript after the span for my UI automation. Here is the line that I have to insert

```
<input type="file" multiple="multiple" class="dz-hidden-input" accept=".pdf" style.display="block" style="visibility: visible; position: fixed; 
  top: 75%;
  left: 75%;">
```

This is the line where I have to insert after the `span`

```
<div id="multi-upload" class="dz-default dz-message"><span>Drop files here to upload</span></div>
```

This is what i tried from my automation script

```
 browser.execute(                                                  

var queryForm = document.getElementById("multi-upload");      
var email = document.createElement("input");                  
email.className = "dz-hidden-input-abc";                              
email.type = "file";                                              
email.style.display="block" ;                                     
email.style="visibility: visible";                                
queryForm.appendChild(email)                                      

);
```

But looks like this is not the correct approach. TIA

Comment: please check this link - https://plainjs.com/javascript/manipulation/insert-an-element-after-or-before-another-32/

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with `browser.execute()`? Your code is syntactically invalid!

Comment: `email.style.visibility="visible";`